# Output Queue pulling based on customer preference

Tags: hp-exstream

In OpenText Exstream , I have a report file which is preferred in Output Queue. Is it possible to exclude/include customer satisfying Queue ,but excluding them in the report file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Go to report file --> Advanced -->Rule run time --> (Change that to before every operation) then write your condition in report file rule (set the required IO and Trigger option correctly)